# How to preserve formatting of text while storing data in mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, rich-text-editor

I'm using HTML5 text editor, using which people can

1. Make text bold/italics.
2. Insert link/image.
3. Change text color, add bullet/numbers etc.

How do I store and retrieve this data in/from mysql database so that the formatting is preserved? Currently, the text is getting stored, but as plain text.

What approach should I adopt to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `htmlentities()` function and in MySQL use TEXT as field type of the attribute

let the element has id `editor`
then in js 
use

`$('#editor').html();`

Example:

```
<div id="editor">
  <!--Here goes your content from HTML5 Editor-->
</div>
```

so use AJAX to save it:

```
function StoreText() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "true") {
                //success message
            } else {
                //error message
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "Update.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("value=" + $('#editor').html());
}
```

Comment: htmlentities() is a php function. I want to retrieve the html part in js and post it via php to insert into mysql.

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to insert html text into db. Is there some similar method that can be used to fetch this html text from db and display formatted text on screen using php. I tried using htmlspecialchars method but it didn't help.

Comment: Glad that I have helped you!